# PircBot script only ops can use?

Tags: java, irc

Trying out Java. I am not good at Java at all. Just want a bot that responds to commands like
"!r1" to then output "Rule 1, No spam"

Need multiple lines but me being not so good I made this:

```
import org.jibble.pircbot.*;

public class MyBot extends PircBot {

    public MyBot() {
        this.setName("Bot");
    }

    public void onMessage(String channel, String sender,
                       String login, String hostname, String message) {
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("hi")) {
            sendMessage(channel, "Hello!");
            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("lol")) {
                sendMessage(channel, "LOL!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first command works but anything after does not.
It also can be used by anyone and should be op only.

Comment: Tried adding some things but no luck. Strange that it worked first time round but not now :L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got brackets mismatched:

The first `if` encompasses the second, you need to move a bracket to close it:

```
public void onMessage(String channel, String sender,
                   String login, String hostname, String message) {
    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("hi")) {
        sendMessage(channel, "Hello!");
    }
    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("lol")) {
        sendMessage(channel, "LOL!");
    }
}
```